# Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, having, having-clause

I need to use an alias in the WHERE clause, but It keeps telling me that its an unknown column. Is there any way to get around this issue? I need to select records that have a rating higher than x. Rating is calculated as the following alias:

```
sum(reviews.rev_rating)/count(reviews.rev_id) as avg_rating
```

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You could use a HAVING clause, which *can* see the aliases, e.g.

```
 HAVING avg_rating>5
```

but in a where clause you'll need to repeat your expression, e.g.

```
 WHERE (sum(reviews.rev_rating)/count(reviews.rev_id))>5
```

BUT! Not all expressions will be allowed - using an aggregating function like SUM will not work, in which case you'll need to use a HAVING clause.

From the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> It is not allowable to refer to a
>   column alias in a WHERE clause,
>   because the column value might not yet
>   be determined when the WHERE  clause
>   is executed. See [Section B.1.5.4,
>   “Problems with Column Aliases”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html).

Comment: If I repeat the expression, it tells me: "invalid use of group function"

Comment: Have reworded to make it clearer aggregrating functions not allowedd

Comment: Nice explanation, esp. the "but in a where clause... repeat.." part

Comment: This is a fine answer, but please consider the performance implications since `HAVING` executes after the data is fetched and `WHERE` executes before.

Comment: You can't use aggregate functions in a WHERE clause. The WHERE clause only filters rows one at a time, not whole groups.

Answer (score 33):

I don't know if this works in mysql, but using sqlserver you can also just wrap it like:

```
select * from (
  -- your original query
  select .. sum(reviews.rev_rating)/count(reviews.rev_id) as avg_rating 
  from ...) Foo
where Foo.avg_rating ...
```

Answer (score 8):

This question is quite old and one answer already gained 160 votes...

Still I would make this clear: The question is actually *not* about whether alias names can be used in the `WHERE` clause.

```
sum(reviews.rev_rating) / count(reviews.rev_id) as avg_rating
```

is an aggregation. In the `WHERE` clause we restrict records we want from the tables by looking at their values. `sum(reviews.rev_rating)` and `count(reviews.rev_id)`, however, are not values we find in a record; they are values we only get after aggregating the records.

So `WHERE` is inappropriate. We need `HAVING`, as we want to restrict result rows after aggregation. It can't be

```
WHERE avg_rating > 10
```

nor

```
WHERE sum(reviews.rev_rating) / count(reviews.rev_id) > 10
```

hence.

```
HAVING sum(reviews.rev_rating) / count(reviews.rev_id) > 10
```

on the other hand is possible and complies with the SQL standard. Whereas

```
HAVING avg_rating > 10
```

is only possible in MySQL. It is not valid SQL according to the standard, as the `SELECT` clause is supposed to get executed after `HAVING`. From the MySQL docs:

> Another MySQL extension to standard SQL permits references in the HAVING clause to aliased expressions in the select list.
>
> The MySQL extension permits the use of an alias in the HAVING clause for the aggregated column

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT customer_Id AS 'custId', gender, age FROM customer
    WHERE  gender = 'F') AS c
WHERE c.custId = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query is static, you can define it as a view then you can use that alias in the where clause while querying the view.