# Innodb problem . The sql query with alias is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

`SELECT VoteTypeId AS  vcol
  FROM VoteType v 
 WHERE v.VoteTypeId = 4`

and table structure is

```
vcol        VoteType
----------- --------------------------------------------------
1           Yes/No
2           Multiple Choice
4           Qualitative
```

but it turn out error and said  Unknown column 'VoteTypeId'  in 'where clause'

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to write: `SELECT vcol AS VoteTypeId FROM VoteType v WHERE v.vcol = 4` ??

Comment: i want to have a shorter name (eg.col to replace vcol) to represent the column

Comment: eg.
select col as vcol from VoteType v where v.col=4

Comment: but the sql query i mentioned above doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your alias is not set up reversed (but it's not entirely clear from your question), and you can't do it that way. You can't use the alias in the where clause.

If the real column name is `vcol`:

```
select vcol as VoteTypeId from VoteType v where v.vcol = 4
```

See [Can you use an alias is a `WHERE` clause in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql) for an explanation/links regarding why you can't use the alias in the `WHERE`.