# MySql Select Query - Getting errors from WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, select

I'm new in MySQL.

```
SELECT
     receive_item.RECEIPT_ID,
     receive_item.ITEM_ID, 
     (receive_item.QTY - delivery_item.QTY) AS QtyRemained 
FROM receive_item
INNER JOIN delivery_item
ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = delivery_item.ITEM_ID 
AND receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = delivery_item.RECEIVE_ID
```

This is the result from the query above

```
RECEIPT_ID ITEM_ID  QTYRemained
    1         1         0
    2         2         0
    3         3         1
    4         4         0
    5         5         0
```

I want to show only the rows where a value of QTYRemained is not 0. 
Something like this

```
RECEIPT_ID ITEM_ID  QTYRemained
    3         3         1
```

I got an error when i added "From QTYRemained != 0" to the end of the select query above.
Can somebody tell me why it's not working?

Comment: You forgot the WHERE clause. I don't see WHERE clause in your code.

Comment: Error messages are useful. You should post yours as part of your question

Comment: To add to what Phil was saying, are you getting an actual error message like the query is invalid or is it just returning 0 results? Because that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I'm an old stick-in-the-mud and refuse to use `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` clause, here's an alternative solution

```
SELECT
     ri.RECEIPT_ID,
     ri.ITEM_ID, 
     (ri.QTY - di.QTY) AS QtyRemained 
FROM receive_item ri
INNER JOIN delivery_item di
ON ri.ITEM_ID = di.ITEM_ID 
AND ri.RECEIPT_ID = di.RECEIVE_ID
WHERE ri.QTY > di.QTY
```

Pretty simple really

Answer (score 2):

Add at the very end

```
WHERE QtyRemained > 0
```

so...

```
SELECT
     receive_item.RECEIPT_ID,
     receive_item.ITEM_ID, 
     (receive_item.QTY - delivery_item.QTY) AS QtyRemained 
FROM receive_item
INNER JOIN delivery_item
ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = delivery_item.ITEM_ID 
AND receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = delivery_item.RECEIVE_ID
WHERE QtyRemained > 0
```

Comment: You can't use "QtyRemained " alias in where

Answer (score 2):

Use `having` instead of `where`.

```
SELECT
     receive_item.RECEIPT_ID,
     receive_item.ITEM_ID, 
     (receive_item.QTY - delivery_item.QTY) AS QtyRemained 
FROM receive_item
INNER JOIN delivery_item
ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = delivery_item.ITEM_ID 
AND receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = delivery_item.RECEIVE_ID
having QtyRemained > 0
```

OR you can do like below:

```
SELECT
     receive_item.RECEIPT_ID,
     receive_item.ITEM_ID, 
     (receive_item.QTY - delivery_item.QTY) AS QtyRemained 
FROM receive_item
INNER JOIN delivery_item
ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = delivery_item.ITEM_ID 
AND receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = delivery_item.RECEIVE_ID
where (receive_item.QTY - delivery_item.QTY) > 0
```

Comment: No man... Not true always.here problem is with the alias. we cant't use in where. I tried and its working

Comment: I'd be more inclined to create the query as a view (even an inline view). `HAVING` is *really* only for applying conditions to aggregate columns

Comment: @Phil see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql sixteen upvote for same answer

Comment: @Teez that particular question is referring to aggregate columns (`SUM` and `COUNT`) which would include a `GROUP BY`

Comment: I Think It will make implicit group by with primary key column if we will not specify. that will make no difference

Comment: @bowlerae MySQL has a generous helping of pixie dust to take care of things like that. Being able to exclude non-aggregate columns from `GROUP BY` statements is another

Comment: Right phil. I aslo depends on table structure

Answer (score 1):

Try:-

```
SELECT
     receive_item.RECEIPT_ID,
     receive_item.ITEM_ID, 
     (receive_item.QTY - delivery_item.QTY) AS QtyRemained 
FROM receive_item
INNER JOIN delivery_item
ON receive_item.ITEM_ID = delivery_item.ITEM_ID 
AND receive_item.RECEIPT_ID = delivery_item.RECEIVE_ID
group by receive_item.RECEIPT_ID
Having QtyRemained > 0
```

Comment: You can't use "QtyRemained " alias in where

Comment: where is the "where" ? I have not added any where.