# Sql Query not working?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why this query is not returning data of 2011 and 2012. Can anyone help me out.Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT 
    country_code,
    SUM(`attendance`) as k6_attendance,
    count(*) as total_events ,
    IF(MONTH(`session_date`)<5,YEAR(`session_date`),YEAR(`session_date`)+1) as YR2
  FROM `v_knowledge_session` v
  WHERE  session_date >0 
  Group by YR2,country_code
  HAVING YR2>(YEAR(NOW())-2) AND country_code='IN'
  ORDER BY country_code,YR2;
```

Comment: Post some of the records for `session_date` and `country_code` from the table.

Comment: provide your table structure also..
means description of your table..

Comment: Are you sure you have data with country_code='IN' *and* session_date in the past 2.5 years? Can you post a table description (`DESCRIBE v_knowledge_session;` and some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause seems to me to be too shabby.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in a subselect, then making the comparison on YR2 afterwards in the outer query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        country_code,
        SUM(attendance) AS k6_attendance,
        COUNT(*) AS total_events,
        IF(MONTH(session_date)<5,YEAR(session_date),YEAR(session_date)+1) AS YR2
    FROM v_knowledge_session v
    WHERE session_date > 0 AND country_code = 'IN'
    GROUP BY YR2, country_code
) a
WHERE 
    a.YR2 > YEAR(NOW())-2
ORDER BY 
    a.country_code, a.YR2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same expression in places other than ORDER BY clause

```
SELECT country_code,SUM(`attendance`) as k6_attendance,count(*) as total_events , 
    IF(MONTH(`session_date`)<5,YEAR(`session_date`),YEAR(`session_date`)+1) as YR2 
    FROM `v_knowledge_session` v 
    WHERE  session_date >0  
    Group by IF(MONTH(`session_date`)<5,YEAR(`session_date`),YEAR(`session_date`)+1) ,country_code 
    HAVING IF(MONTH(`session_date`)<5,YEAR(`session_date`),YEAR(`session_date`)+1) >(YEAR(NOW())-2) AND country_code='IN' 
    ORDER BY country_code,YR2;
```

Comment: Use of column or expression *aliases* in `having` is acceptable. Refer [*here*](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use non-aggregated condition in `HAVING` clause. `country_code='IN'` must be in the `WHERE` clause. The reason why `HAVING` clause was created is because the `WHERE` clause cannot handle aggregated condition. In your query, `having` clause is not needed because your condition is not aggregated. Also you can remove the `ALIAS` *v*

try this one:

```
SELECT    country_code, 
          SUM(`attendance`) as k6_attendance,
          count(*) as total_events ,
          IF(MONTH(`session_date`) < 5 ,
               YEAR(`session_date`),
               YEAR(`session_date`) + 1) as YR2
FROM      `v_knowledge_session` 
WHERE      session_date > 0 AND country_code='IN' AND YR2 > (YEAR(NOW())-2) 
Group by  YR2, country_code
ORDER BY  country_code,YR2;
```

Comment: No. Use of column or expression *aliases* in `having` is acceptable, but not in `where` clause. Refer [*here*](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx), [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql) and at [*Problems with Column Aliases*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html) too.