# Filtering data from joined mysql table using Where Clause

Tags: mysql

How to filter data in the below query using where clause for Balance column. I'm getting the error [Unknown column "Balance" in "where clause"] when i use Balance in where condition.

```
select *,(it.Total - p.Amount) as Balance
from invoices i
left outer join invoice_items it
    on i.ID=it.InvoiceID
left outer join payment p
    on p.InvoiceID=it.InvoiceID 
where Balance!=0;
```

And also, when there is no matching payment record found, instead of displaying the null value in Balance column, i need the Total value of the invoice_items table.

Comment: `where (it.Total - p.Amount) != 0;` should works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an alias in a where clause.

rewrite

```
where (it.Total - p.Amount) <> 0
```

and for the other part

```
  select 
   (case when p.PaymentId IS NULL 
    then it.Total
    else
    (it.Total - p.Amount) 
   end)
```

or. COALESCE means : if p.Amount is null, use 0. Else use p.Amount

```
select it.Total - COALESCE(p.Amount, 0)
```

FINALLY

```
select i.*,(it.Total - COALESCE(p.Amount, 0)) as Balance
from invoices i
left outer join invoice_items it
    on i.ID=it.InvoiceID
left outer join payment p
    on p.InvoiceID=it.InvoiceID 
where it.Total - COALESCE(p.Amount, 0) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *,(it.Total - p.Amount) as Balance
from invoices i
left outer join invoice_items it
    on i.ID=it.InvoiceID
left outer join payment p
    on p.InvoiceID=it.InvoiceID 
where (it.Total - p.Amount) <> 0;
```

You cannot use an alias in where clause, because chronologically, WHERE happens before SELECT, which always is the last step in the execution chain.