# Left Excluding JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this working MySQL query (it's stripped down to show only relevant lines):

```
SELECT
  c.id AS id_comment
, bl.id_user AS block
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN user_blocked AS bl ON 
  (c.id_user = bl.id_user AND :uid = bl.id_user_blocked) 
  OR (c.id_user = bl.id_user_blocked AND :uid = bl.id_user)
WHERE (c.id_title = :idt)
```

It works! But I just want to get results where `block IS NULL` so I add a new condition in `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
  c.id AS id_comment
, bl.id_user AS block
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN user_blocked AS bl ON 
  (c.id_user = bl.id_user AND :uid = bl.id_user_blocked) 
  OR (c.id_user = bl.id_user_blocked AND :uid = bl.id_user)
WHERE (c.id_title = :idt) AND (block IS NULL)
```

But I get this error:

```
SQL ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
Unknown column 'block' in 'where clause'
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`block` is an `ALIAS`, you should be using the name of the column instead

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE (c.id_title = :idt) AND (bl.id_user IS NULL)
```

the reason why it is not found is because the order of operation is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

If you want `block` to be used instead of the column name, you need to put the entire query in a `SubQuery`. eg

```
SELECT  * 
FROM
(
    SELECT  c.id AS id_comment, 
            bl.id_user AS block
    FROM    comments AS c
            LEFT JOIN user_blocked AS bl 
                ON  (c.id_user = bl.id_user AND :uid = bl.id_user_blocked) OR 
                (c.id_user = bl.id_user_blocked AND :uid = bl.id_user)
    WHERE   c.id_title = :idt
) s
WHERE block IS NULL
```

*but I prefer the first solution than using a subquery*.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reference the column alias; reference the true column instead:

```
WHERE (c.id_title = :idt) AND (bl.id_user IS NULL)
```

Comment: @Peter Careful (;>). And please accept JW's answer; it's more complete and beat me to it.

Comment: Merry Christmas and Happy New Year Bob! `+1`

Comment: Happy new year to both of you! Thanks again :)