# Age calculation not working

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am receiving an error during my age calculation.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, '%m/%d/%Y'))) age, name
FROM pers 
WHERE age >= 50 
ORDER BY age DESC 
LIMIT 100;
```

Here is the error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'age' in 'where clause'

"age" will output just fine when i remove the where clause, it just will not allow me to use it as a condition and im not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use column aliases in `WHERE` clauses. Use the entire expression or use the `HAVING` clause, although that is only applied after the `ORDER BY` (so it could be quite inefficient with large datasets).

Comment: I see what you are saying, I did not realize the alias could not be used in a WHERE clause. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, '%m/%d/%Y'))) age, name
 FROM pers 
 WHERE (YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(birthdate, '%m/%d/%Y')))  >= 50 
 ORDER BY age DESC 
 LIMIT 100;
```

you can use the aliace age in where clause

[here an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql) to if you can use aliaces in whre clause

Comment: Thanks for the help, the guy above beat you to it! I appreciate the resource be HAVING wont work well as its over a million rows of data. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like you have one bracket too many, here : '%m/%d/%Y')))

Comment: No he doesn't. The bracketing is fine.

Comment: Right. I missed the closing bracket after the first `CURDATE`. However, it is probably a copy error, as he says that the query runs fine without the `WHERE`.

Comment: Yes- haha- brackets have always been the cause of my most annoying sql problems! Maybe you can remove my downvote- i was just trying to be helpful, after all!

Comment: @user2152812: If the answer is incorrect then it's better to remove the answer than to remove the downvote.

Comment: Not so David- it is a matter of principle. Brackets are a perennial source of issues with sql statements, particularly ones that are very complex. There was a bracket problem- and I pointed it out- it might not have been his issue- but the bracketing was wrong and that usually will cause issues.