# PHP and SQL | Specific thing in query

Tags: php, mysql

In DB I have a field that contains user's birthday. Example: 01.09.1994
I have a PHP function that calculates of user's birth. 
Now the thing that I want to do:
I want to search all the users with age 18 for example, but I want to do this in the sql query. How can this happen?

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `birth` = '18'"
```

How with sql to automatically turn the birth(01.09.1994) into ages, without getting the results and then turn the birthday in ages with php?

Comment: What is the data type of date value ? Show some sample data.

Comment: You should be able to calculate the age in the query.

Comment: I already said. Data is saved this way for every user d.m.y(01.06.1993)

Comment: @JayBlanchard But I'm asking how :D ?

Comment: I know you are, but we're not going to write your query for you :D I'll give you a hint - look up MySQL's date functions, like `DATE_SUB()`

Comment: `01.09.1994` is a string, not a date. it would be easier if you formatted your data to use a proper date column/type https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html then you could use standard date/time functions to do what you want https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Query to get age from date of birth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734739/mysql-query-to-get-age-from-date-of-birth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date you are saving is not a real date and it needs to be converted to real date using `str_to_date` function and then using the `timestampdiff` you can get the age as

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(year,str_to_date('01.06.1993','%d.%m.%Y'),curdate()) as age ;
+------+
| age  |
+------+
|   21 |
+------+
```

So if the column name is `dob` in the table and you want to find all the users having age = 18 you can do as

```
select * from users
where 
timestampdiff(year,str_to_date(dob,'%d.%m.%Y'),curdate()) = 18
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer fit perfectly in my query and it works find for now!