# MySQL query within if condition

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, case, conditional-statements

I have the following tables:

USERS:

> id,username,owner

ADMINS

> id,username,owner

TRANSACTIONS:

> id,sender_id,sender_type

Each user can be owned by an admin
Each admin can be owned by another admin

I am trying to work on some access levels and I want to retrieve the query rows that have the owner of the sender part of a list generated through PHP.

For this I need to get the owner of the sender based on the data I have, without having to alter the database structure:

```
SELECT 
    * ,
    IF (t.sender_type='admin',
        ( SELECT owner AS qowner 
          FROM admins
          WHERE id=t.sender_id),
          ( SELECT owner AS qowner FROM users 
            WHERE id=t.sender_id)
    ) AS qowner 
FROM `transactions` t 
WHERE qowner IN ('admin22','admin33','admin44','admin66')
```

I keep getting this error : **Unknown column 'qowner' in 'where clause'**

I am now stuck at this.
I will appreciate all help coming.
Thank you!

Comment: You are using `qowner` alias three times for different things, that's why the error

Comment: I removed the aliases and used it only after the IF query and still same issue.

Comment: That is because you are trying to use an alias in the where clause. The alias name effectively doesn't exist until after the WHERE clause has been evaluated - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be trying to refer to a column from the subselects within the WHERE clause I think.

However no need for subselects:-

```
SELECT * ,
IF (t.sender_type='admin', a.owner, b.owner) AS qowner 
FROM transactions t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN admins a ON t.sender_id = a.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users b ON t.sender_id = a.id
HAVING qowner IN ('admin22','admin33','admin44','admin66')
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to refer to a column from the subselects. Will try this and let you know

Comment: I used my own query, but instead of WHERE, I used HAVING, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * ,
IF (t.sender_type='admin',(SELECT owner FROM admins WHERE id=t.sender_id),(SELECT owner FROM users WHERE id=t.sender_id)) AS qowner 
FROM transactions t 
WHERE qowner IN ('admin22','admin33','admin44','admin66')
```

(untested)

Comment: Modified the query into this: "SELECT * ,IF (t.sender_type='admin',(SELECT owner FROM admins WHERE id=t.sender_id),(SELECT owner FROM users WHERE id=t.sender_id)) AS qowner FROM `transactions` t WHERE qowner IN ('admin22','admin33','admin44','admin66')" and I am getting same error. Thanks for the help anyway