# mysql CONCAT () AS name?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create little search engine for only a small database.
"CONCAT () AS name" does not work so how can I use something like Concat() as xxx ?

Created an example here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21b5c/5

What I try to do is

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(names,' ',office) AS bigDataField
    FROM item_table 
WHERE bigDataField LIKE "%jessy%";
```

What is the best way to use the concat field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `HAVING` clause, rather than duplicating the `CONCAT()` function in your `WHERE` clause.

For example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`names`,' ',`office`) `bigDataField`
       FROM `item_table` 
HAVING `bigDataField` LIKE "%jessy%";
```

Comment: Pay attention: `HAVING` will be executed after the query. MySQL first execute the query and than apply having clause to the result set.

Comment: In my opinion "where concat" is better.

Comment: It depends upon your data set, and how many results you expect. I've never been a big fan of calling the same function twice. You wouldn't run a Haversine formula in the select AND where clauses.

Comment: the select gets called by ajax on keyup + a few ms. I try to make a dynamic search

Comment: I'd recommend `HAVING` then.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use aliases in `where` clauses.

```
SELECT CONCAT(names,' ',office) AS bigDataField
FROM item_table 
WHERE CONCAT(names,' ',office) LIKE "%jessy%";
```

Comment: thank you guys so much for your resposnes! is it better to use HAVING like BenM writes? If I look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21b5c/10 one time your example is faster and another time benms example

Comment: `having` clauses are for grouped data. For the sake of readability I would differ to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use an alias for a calculated column in a `WHERE` clause - you will need to use `CONCAT(names,' ',office)` instead in your `WHERE` clause.

This post has more detail: [Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)