# MySQL Concat .. As

Tags: mysql

I am trying to put an alias for the result of a concat command in MySQL, I have seen it done in different questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141695/mysql-concat-as-name) however it doesn't seem to be working with me.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`firstname`,' ',`lastname`) FROM `cms_users` AS username
```

The result is coming up like this:

```
[0] => Array
     (
        [CONCAT(`firstname`,' ',`lastname`)] => fname lname
     )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CONCAT(`firstname`,' ',`lastname`)] => fname lname
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [CONCAT(`firstname`,' ',`lastname`)] => fname lname
    )
```

The end result I am after is this:

```
[0] => Array
     (
        [username] => fname lname
     )

[1] => Array
    (
        [username] => fname lname
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [username] => fname lname
    )
```

Comment: Try SELECT CONCAT(`firstname`,' ',`lastname`) AS username FROM `cms_users`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(`firstname`,' ',`lastname`) FROM `cms_users` AS username
```

change this to

```
SELECT CONCAT(`firstname`,' ',`lastname`) AS username FROM `cms_users`
```

in your query your actually giving alias to table name which is wrong
the alias should be given to column name.

Answer (score 0):

Give alias name for column not for the table.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`firstname`,' ',`lastname`) username FROM `cms_users`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS username FROM cms_users`