# Add prefix text to select statement

Tags: mysql, string-concatenation

I am trying to run a select statement on two different servers that have some matching primary keys. I want to be able to select the primary key but add the prefix 'A' to every record

ex:

```
ID   "to this"   ID
1                A1
2                A2
3                A3
```

This is what I have for the query

```
select 'A' + CAST (a.id AS VARCHAR(25)) as ID,a.*,':',     b.*,':',c.*,':', d.*,':', e.*,'REPORTDT', g.*
from labgen.order_ a
join patient b on a.id = b.chart
join insurance c on b.ins1 = c.code
join client d on d.num = a.client1
join salesgrp e on d.salesgroup = e.num
join reportdt g on a.accession = g.accession
```

Comment: You're looking for CONCAT()

Comment: select CONCAT('A',a.id).       You are correct sir, don't know why i couldn't think of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the select statement:

```
select CONCAT('A', a.id) as ID, a.*,':', //etc
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141695/mysql-concat-as-name) link will also help.

Comment: well that first line can't all be a concat as I see it

Comment: It's not, I just wrote the part of the query before the first comma

Comment: Yea I see what you mean, there isn't a need for CAST() in this situation