# MySQL - using REGEXP on an alias of a subquery

Tags: mysql, regex

How can I use REGEXP on an alias of a subquery?

```
SELECT 
    colA,
    colB,
    (SELECT colA FROM t2 WHERE t1.colID=t2.colID) as colC
FROM t1
WHERE colC REGEXP '$string'
ORDER BY IF($col = '' OR $col IS NULL,1,0),$col";
```

It works if I make another select of the complete query, but I see that this costs some time

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        colA,
        colB,
        (SELECT colA FROM t2 WHERE t1.colID=t2.colID) as colC
    FROM t1
) as temp
WHERE colC REGEXP '$string'
ORDER BY IF($col = '' OR $col IS NULL,1,0),$col";
```

REGEXP works if I use a join and referencing the table field directly, but the order doesn't work with an alias either

```
SELECT 
    t1.colA AS colA,
    t1.colB AS colB,
    t2.colA AS colC
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.colID=t2.colID
WHERE t2.colA REGEXP '$string'
ORDER BY IF($col = '' OR $col IS NULL,1,0),$col";
```

So is a select on the complete query the only way to do what I need?

Comment: In general, the `WHERE` clause of a given scope cannot see aliases defined in its `SELECT` list (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)).  The join is likely to be a lot more performant than the subselect anyway, if you use the `table.column` instead of the alias.

Comment: Can you explain why your last example doesn't work? (FWIW: I think the LEFT JOIN is not needed because of the WHERE clause. You could write the LEFT JOIN and WHERE as `JOIN t2 ON t1.colID=t2.colID AND t2.colA REGEXP '$string'`)

Comment: It seems that the alias can't be used in the IF clause. I use the Left Join because not all rows have a join entry and I want all rows from table1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HAVING clause (this is not standard SQL - MySQL feature):

```
SELECT 
    colA,
    colB,
    (SELECT colA FROM t2 WHERE t1.colID=t2.colID) as colC
FROM t1
HAVING colC REGEXP '$string'
ORDER BY IF($col = '' OR $col IS NULL,1,0),$col";
```

There are performance implications - your join is a better query.