# How to do a "where" clause on data from join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do an `SQL` query to get all the messages sent between 2 users: the "Sender" and the "Reciever" (yes I know this is spelled wrong) are foreign keys to the `Users` table.

I want to get back all the messages that the current user sent or received along with the username of the other person involved in the message.

I have the `JOIN` working (if I delete the `where` clause I get all messages), however I can't figure out how to restrict it using the `where`.

```
mysql_query(sprintf("
SELECT m.Content, us.Name Send, ur.Name Rec, m.Timestamp
FROM Messages m
JOIN Users us ON us.UserID = m.Sender
JOIN Users ur ON ur.UserID = m.Reciever
WHERE Send = '%s' or Rec = '%s'
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
"), $user, $user);
```

Comment: Go on. Have a go. Also, look at IN()

Comment: SELECT m.Content, us.Name Send, ur.Name Rec, m.Timestamp
FROM Messages m
JOIN Users us ON us.UserID = m.Sender
JOIN Users ur ON ur.UserID = m.Reciever
WHERE us.Name = '%s' or ur.Name = '%s'
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC

Comment: Strawberry, I am not clear on what you are suggesting.
cyadvert, I dont think that worked, I get no results

Comment: @cyadvert I think the OP meant `LIKE` and not `=` where the wildcard `%` is used.

Comment: @user2989408: looks like OP meant an equality comparison. That "`%`"  character isn't a SQL wildcard. The "`%s`" is a tag for sprintf replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a column alias in the `WHERE` clause. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql).

Your `WHERE` clause should be:

```
WHERE us.Name = '%s' OR ur.Name = '%s'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just change it slightly like below

```
SELECT m.Content, us.Name as Send,
ur.Name as Rec, 
m.Timestamp
FROM Messages m
JOIN Users us ON us.UserID = m.Sender
JOIN Users ur ON ur.UserID = m.Reciever
WHERE us.Name = '%s' or ur.Name = '%s' <-- Change Here
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```