# How to use alias variable for condition in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT mob_no,

  (SELECT max(str_to_date(debit_date,'%d/%m/%Y'))
   FROM client_debit_bal
   WHERE mob_no='".$mobno."') AS date,
       sum(debit_amt) AS debit
FROM client_debit_bal
WHERE date_format(str_to_date(debit_date,'%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')= date
```

Actually here `date` is a alias variable and i cant able to use for condition. Please help me to overcome this problem.

Sample Data's

```
-----------------------------------
date       | cre_amount  |   mob_no
------------------------------------
23/01/2013 |    100     | 123456
------------------------------------
24/01/2013 |    500     | 123456
------------------------------------
25/01/2013 |    500     | 123456
------------------------------------
26/01/2013 |    900     | 123456
------------------------------------
29/01/2013 |    1000     | 123456
------------------------------------
29/01/2013 |    1300     | 123456
------------------------------------
29/01/2013 |    1200     | 123456
------------------------------------
```

Expected Output is `max(date)` and `sum(cre_amount)` and Result is `3500`

(Which means select maximum `date` and return the sum of `cre_amount`from maximum date)

Comment: For future reference, the correct term is "alias". This will be helpful in letter others understand what you're referring to

Comment: Did you look at this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql

Comment: ***@user3770172***: Show some sample data and some expected rows

Comment: I have give some sample data ... please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply this

```
select DATE_FORMAT(max(cast(str_to_date(`date`, '%d/%m/%Y') as date)),'%d/%m/%Y'),
   sum(cre_amount) from table1 where date=(select DATE_FORMAT(max(cast(str_to_date(`date`, '%d/%m/%Y') as date)),'%d/%m/%Y') 
     from table1)
```