# Use the result of the MySQL SELECT query as a WHERE condition in the same query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do this query:

```
SELECT MAX(`peg_num`)
  AS "indicator"
FROM `list`
WHERE `list_id` = 1
  AND "indicator" >= 1
```

But I'm getting the result of `NULL`. What I should be getting is `99`, as the range of `peg_num` is 00 to 99.

The value checked against "indicator" should actually be a user input, so I want it to be versatile. But, it *does* give me the correct result if I flip the equality around:

```
SELECT MAX(`peg_num`)
  AS "indicator"
FROM `list`
WHERE `list_id` = 1
  AND "indicator" <= 1
```

Why would it do this?

Edit:

As suggested, I'm using the HAVING clause... but I just ditched the alias for now anyway:

```
SELECT MAX(`peg_num`) AS "indicator"
FROM `list`
GROUP BY `list_id`
HAVING MAX(`peg_num`) <= 40
```

Still very stubborn. It gives me 99 now no matter the value in the having clause, regardless of the inequality.

Edit2:

As a clarification:

What I want to happen is the query select the largest value in the range of peg_num, but only if it is larger than a user-given input. So, the max in this case is 99. If the user wants to select a number like 101, he/she can't because it's not in the range.

Comment: which mysql version are you using? I can't reproduce...

Comment: Server version: 5.6.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL). What result are you getting?

Comment: alias should not be surrounded with double quote, use tick instead

Comment: tried this but no go :(

Comment: Oh! Of course! It's actually a char type. ... But I just went ahead and corrected that and it still doesn't do what I want. It seems like the number value being compared to "indicator" doesnt matter, it's the sign. If I use "<=" it will give me 99, but if I use ">=" it will give me null

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you should use peg_num >= 1 instead of idicator >= 1 (indicator is an alias formed using aggregate function max and it is not valid for where clause - you could use having as suggested earlier though)

Comment: Tried using having but still having problems, I updated the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely re-invented my query and it worked. The thing is, I had to use a nested query (and I wanted to not do that as much as possible, my professor had always discouraged it).

Anyway, here it is:

```
SELECT IF(`key` < 900, `key`, null) `key`
FROM (
(

    SELECT MAX(  `peg_num` ) AS  `key` 
    FROM  `list` 
    WHERE  `list_id` =1
    ) AS  `derivedTable`
)
```

Comment: you can do this without nested query: select case when MAX(  `peg_num` )< 900 then MAX(  `peg_num` ) else null end as key from `list` WHERE  `list_id` =1

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the link on the answer to another Stack question about not being allowed to use alias in where clause:

[Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Paul Dixon cites:

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause,
>   because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE
>   clause is executed. See Section B.1.5.4, “[Problems with Column
>   Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)”.

Also:

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.

The behavior you're seeing in your query when you swap the '<=' and '>=' operators, results from the query comparing the string/varchar 'indicator' to the number 1.

That's why you see the correct answer..when ('indicator' >= 1) which is true, and null when ('indicator' <= 1) which is false.

Answer (score 1):

1. Because of double quotes, `"indicator"` in `WHERE` clause is interpreted as a string. Thus, it evaluates to 0, meaning it is always less than 1. Column names must be escaped in backticks.
2. Keep in mind that `WHERE` clause is executed before `SELECT` an hence aliases defined in `SELECT` can not be used in `WHERE` clause.

   ```
   SELECT MAX(`peg_num`) AS `indicator`
   FROM `list`
   WHERE `list_id` = 1
   HAVING `indicator` >= 1
   ```

Comment: this gives me a 99 if I change >=1 to >=1000 or <=1 or <=1000 :(

Comment: Can you check the query twice? It's impossible to get 99 with the condition `indicator >= 1000` :-)

Answer (score 0):

WHERE happens before SELECT, and don't know what's "indicator".

You should use HAVING (with GROUP BY) to use the SELECT fields

Here's the documentation for syntax

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Something like this is the idea

```
SELECT MAX(peg_num) AS indicator
FROM list
WHERE list_id = 1
HAVING indicator <= 1
```

I can't test it and i never met Mysql so just the idea,

Comment: (I was saying: WHERE don't know, i do) but you can't use aggregation functions in WHERE clause and i am sure that the order of execution is something like: FROM, WHERE, SELECT, HAVING (so you can't use AS in SELECT a then use it in WHERE. but you can use it in FROM). All this if we don't talk about sub-querys. If i am wrong let me know please, give some link

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I'm amazed either of them work at all. WHERE works serially on fields belonging to individual records and I wouldn't expect it to work on "indicator" since that's a group calculation.

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT max(`peg_num` ) AS "indicator"
FROM actions
WHERE `peg_num` >=1
AND `list_id` <= 1
```

Comment: Not exactly. What I want it to do is to get the max value of peg_num (in this case, 99), but only if that max value is greater than some user input. But thanks for the info, I didn't know aliases couldn't be used in the WHERE clause up til now

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use HAVING
2. No quotes in HAVING condition

This must work:

```
SELECT MAX(peg_num)
 AS indicator
FROM list
WHERE list_id = 1
  HAVING indicator >= 1
```

Comment: remove the quotes from the alias... either leave the alias with no enclosing characters, or enclose it between backticks