# I dont understand what I did wrong

Tags: mysql

> If I run below query in my phpmyadmin it throw me below error
>
> **> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'QTY' in 'where clause'**

```
SELECT User_Name,
       COUNT(User_Name) AS QTY
FROM preusage
WHERE QTY > 1
GROUP BY User_Name
```

Please somebody help me

Comment: you cannot use alias name in where conditions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: This make no sense... Is your interest to count user_name usage ?
Maybe you should prefer to check if exist (registering new user ?)
If you really want to get user name used more than once, please use HAVING... But it could reveal a designing mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.

But in your case I guess instead you want to use `having` anyway (which can use previously defined  aliases)

```
SELECT User_Name, COUNT(User_Name) as QTY 
FROM preusage 
GROUP BY User_Name
HAVING QTY > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use having instead of where clause as you are using group by

```
SELECT User_Name,
       COUNT(User_Name) AS QTY
FROM preusage
GROUP BY User_Name HAVING User_Name > 1
```