# Query builder using alias name inside a query

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to have a Query build like this:

```
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select(
        'af.shortKey as wg, 
        af.id as afId', 
        'afl.name as afName', 
        'l.id as langId') // -> this one
        ->from('DatabaseBundle:ArticleFamily', 'af')
        ->leftJoin('af.articleFamilyLanguages', 'afl')
        ->leftJoin('afl.language', 'l')
        ->where('langId = :languageId') //-> this is causing the problem
        //if i use it like l.id = :languageId is working. But I don't want it like this.
        ->setParameter('languageId', $params['lang']);
```

I need to use it like this because I am passing some parameters in the url and I cannot use `l.id`

If I am using this query I am getting the following error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT a0_.short_key AS
>   short_key0, a0_.id AS id1, a1_.name AS name2, l2_.id AS id3 FROM
>   article_family a0_ LEFT JOIN article_family_language a1_ ON a0_.id =
>   a1_.article_family_id LEFT JOIN language l2_ ON a1_.language_id =
>   l2_.id WHERE id3 = ? ORDER BY name2 ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0' with params
>   ["3"]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id3' in 'where
>   clause'

Where id3 should be actually `l2_.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot using field alias in `WHERE` clause. Instead, you could try with `HAVING`.

Related SO question/answer: [Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)