# Where statement that will use a concat

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT zlec_status.nazwa                       AS Status, 
       piorytet.nazwa                          AS Priorytet, 
       Concat(koord.imie, ' ', koord.nazwisko) AS `Koordynator`, 
       Concat(zlec_adresy.town, ' - ', zlec_adresy.street, ' ', 
       zlec_adresy.other) 
                                               AS `adres`, 
       zlec_z_dnia,zlec_id, 
       zlec_nr, 
       zlec_do, 
       zlec_ogran, 
       awizacje, 
       awizacja_na_dzien, 
       termin_zamkniecia, 
       tresc, 
       uwagi 
FROM   zlec 
       INNER JOIN koord 
               ON zlec.koord = koord.id 
       INNER JOIN zlec_adresy 
               ON zlec.zlec_addres = zlec_adresy.id 
       INNER JOIN piorytet 
               ON zlec.priorytet = piorytet.id 
       INNER JOIN zlec_status 
               ON zlec.status_zlecenia = zlec_status.id 
WHERE  `zlec_adresy`.`town` LIKE  '%Sz%' LIMIT 0, 10
```

The table `zlec_adresy` is the following:

```
=============================   
id | street | town | other
=============================
```

As you see there is a concat for the whole address part

```
Concat(zlec_adresy.town, ' - ', zlec_adresy.street, ' ',zlec_adresy.other)AS `adres`
```

Starting off - the user has a input field with the address lookup - so he can write either the town name or a street name or the other condition. In my code there will be only filtered through the WHERE clause of the .'town' LIKE userinput. But how can I make it working => `Where ||Concat(zlec_adresy.town, ' - ', zlec_adresy.street, ' ',zlec_adresy.other)AS`adres`|| LIKE userinput`

So basically it would filter the As `adres` for the where statement. Is that possible to do? Or there is another way to accomplish it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another, possibly more clean approach uses `OR`:

```
WHERE
  town like concat('%',@userinput,'%')
OR
  street like concat('%',@userinput,'%')
OR 
  other like concat('%',@userinput,'%')
```

Comment: yes this could be also be done so, but I guess I will use the example below

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE 
Concat(zlec_adresy.town, ' - ', zlec_adresy.street, ' ', 
       zlec_adresy.other) like concat('%',@variable,'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HAVING to solve your issue. Something like :

`SELECT 
  name, CONCAT(street, ' ', town) AS address 
FROM
  zlec
WHERE
  zlec.town like '%abc%'
HAVING address like '%xyz%'`

Answer (score 1):

The query anatomy looks like this:

- it handles the `from`, because all the other clauses are dependent on it
- it handles the `where`, to filter out unneeded rows
- it handles the `select`, so you will get the columns you want

Note, that I did not mention `group by`, `having` or `order by`, since they are not part of your query, so this anatomy is quite a simplified one. The purpose of this simplification was to achieve clarity.

Now, since the `select` runs after the `where`, you cannot use the renames from the `select` in the `where`, since when the `where` is executed, the selection was not yet executed.

So you have to do a work-around:
- you can define a temporary new relation by `(select ...) mynewrelation` and use the column renamings of the `newrelation`, but it is not advisable for this very situation. However, it is good to know about this option, it might be useful in the future
- you can use something like the one suggested by Madhivanan, but that solution is not performant, since you are doing very slow string operations to concatenate those fields. As a result, the code will be clear but slow
- Hanno Binder's solution is much better, since it uses the benefit of the `or` of not evaluating the second operand if the first was true. His code is fast, but you do not want to see it

My suggestion: You should define a `stored function` to make this calculation. That stored function should be equivalent to the solution suggested by Hanno Binder and you would just call that function in your query. So, your source-code will be clear, easy-to-read, correct and performant.