# Sql query without sub query and joins

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

To have students (student_id, course_id, course_name) who take exactly only one course, using a simple SQL statement with no sub-query and no join at all

```
student_id  course_id   course_name
---------------------------------------------
1       1000        'CS 101'
2       1000        'CS 101'
1       2000        'CHEM 200'
2       3000        'ENG 211'
3       1000        'CS 101'
4       5000        'Bio 400'
```

Any one please me on this. Tried many approaches but couldn't get the answer without sub query.

Comment: What are some of the approaches you have tried?

Comment: Do you want to get students who have only 1 course associated?

Comment: Why the MySQL tag? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Poorly normalized. Why course_name in this table?

Comment: @jarlh - I guess this is homework: schools tend not bother with niceties like third normal form.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` with `having`

```
select student_id,count(course_id) as num 
from students group by student_id
having num =1
```

or this :-

```
select student_id
from students group by student_id
having count(course_id) =1
```

Comment: you can't use aliases in `having`. It should be `having count(course_id)=1`

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql @Tatiana

Comment: it is valid for MySQL, not for Oracle. And I see tag Oracle here @rahautos

Comment: And he sees the `mysql` tag here too :P

Comment: As far as I know `having count(course_id)=1` will work for both DB

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to retrieve just the STUDENT_ID for students on just one course:

```
SQL>  SELECT student_id
  2   FROM students 
  3   GROUP BY student_id
  4   HAVING COUNT(course_id) = 1 
  5   /


STUDENT_ID
----------
         4
         3

Elapsed: 00:00:00.09
SQL>
```

But to get additional information, such as the course name, then we need to use a sub-query or join.

Answer (score -2):

How about using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT`

```
SELECT student_id, course_name FROM students 
GROUP BY student_id, course_name
HAVING COUNT(course_id) = 1
```

Comment: Having use to filter group data. you should place it just after the group by.

Comment: This query doesn't return the results you think it does.

Comment: Sorry my mistake , `GROUP BY` first before the `HAVING COUNT` , answer already modified... my apologies.