# Using a named count() function in sql where section

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use an alias in a *WHERE* condition?

For example:

```
SELECT n.name, count(c.name) as freq FROM names as n, names as c 
WHERE freq < 1 AND gender = 'f' order by rand() )
```

Or would I have to do this another way?

Comment: My spidey sense tells me you are looking for a `GROUP BY` somewhere.

Comment: ... I may be extremely tired. and that may be the exact thing i'm looking for. pardon me

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you give sample data and expected output? NB: the query is not valid. Do you have a valid one?

Comment: 1) you query seems to be meanless 2) calculated field can not be used in where but can in having clause

Comment: @trincot i'm trying to get the most common name in a database. IE "Emily", "John" or any other generic name.

Comment: `SELECT name, count(*) FROM names GROUP BY name ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: The question is worthy of a self-delete

Comment: You need `HAVING freq < 1` but this will never be true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Comment: Or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/200203/1575353) might be a solution (like dnoeth specified)