# Laravel, MySQL Spatial Point distance: orderBy and get distance

Tags: mysql, laravel, distance, spatial

Can anyone help me get this query right.

I have a `Concert` model and another `Location` model. Concert belongs to a location. Location table has a spatial point field.

I need to do three things:

- order by distance from users location
- display distance from users location
- get concerts that are in some given distance from the users location

So far I have managed to set the database and to get the concerts in a certain distance from the user as:

```
$condition = ($lat != null && $lon != null && $distance != null);
Concert::when($condition, function ($query) use ($distance,$lat,$lon) {
      return $query->whereHas('location', function($query) use ($distance,$lat,$lon) {
          $query->whereRaw('st_distance(location,POINT('.$lat.','.$lon.')) < '.$distance);
      });
  })
->get();
```

Can you help me how to display this `st_distance` in the view?

How would I order this by distance?

What is the proper way to get the `$distance` in miles/kilometers as I read in the docs that `st_distance` is given in degrees?

Answer (score 6):

You can select `ST_DISTANCE` or `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE` ([MySQL Spatial Convenience Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere)) and then:

- Order results using `ORDER BY` sql clause
- Add distance constraint using `HAVING` sql clause ([why can't use WHERE clause here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql))

```php
$raw = 'SELECT
  ST_X(location) AS longitude,
  ST_Y(location) AS latitude,
  ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(location, POINT(?, ?)) AS dist
FROM
  concerts,
  locations
WHERE
  concerts.id = locations.id
HAVING
  dist < ?
ORDER BY
  dist';
$pointsWithDist = DB::select($raw, [$lon, $lat, $distance]);
```

**Notes:**

- store longitude as first param and latitude as second param of `POINT` spatial function
- both `ST_DISTANCE` and `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE` return distance in **meters** by default

you can use google maps to display data