# error in my mysql query with a limit condition

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

i have 3 tables
customers, times and sales
i want to find out all the customers income yearly condition is that customers with no children and income must be greater than a limit we are set
my table structure
customers

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_num` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mi` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address3` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address4` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `region_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone1` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `marital_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `yearly_income` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_children` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_children_at_home` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `education` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `member_card` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occupation` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `houseowner` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_cars_owned` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

sales

```
CREATE TABLE `sales` (
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_sales` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_cost` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_sales` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

times

```
CREATE TABLE `times` (
  `time_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `the_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `the_day` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `the_month` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `the_year` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_of_month` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `month_of_year` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

MY question is :-Find the list of the customers with no child and an yearly_income greater that a limit given by the user when running the query.

MY query is

```
SET @limit=50;
SELECT customers.`fname`, customers.`lname` ,ROUND(SUM(sales.store_sales)) as income,times.the_year
 FROM `sales` 
 LEFT JOIN times
 ON sales.time_id=times.time_id
 LEFT JOIN customers 
ON customers.customer_id=sales.customer_id 
WHERE income>@limit AND `total_children`=0
GROUP BY sales.customer_id,times.the_year
```

am getting this error:#1054 - Unknown column 'income' in 'where clause'

Comment: I've removed sql server tag, as you use mysql. Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: should be `yearly_income` instead of `income`

Comment: not such a field yearly_income

Comment: income is calculated as ROUND(SUM(sales.store_sales)) as income i want this in that where condition

Comment: Why is `yearly_income` a varchar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: `yearly_income` is a column in `customers`, I doubt it's related to the sum of sales.

Comment: Wow, `total_children` is a `smallint(6)`, must be sperm donors :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity you aliased as `income` is an aggregate, and therefore it does not make sense to refer to it in the `WHERE` clause.  Move this `WHERE` logic to a `HAVING` clause:

```
SET @limit=50;
SELECT
    c.fname,
    c.lname,
    ROUND(SUM(s.store_sales)) AS income,
    t.the_year
FROM sales s 
LEFT JOIN times t
    ON s.time_id = t.time_id
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON c.customer_id = s.customer_id 
WHERE
    total_children = 0
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id,
    t.the_year 
HAVING
    ROUND(SUM(s.store_sales)) > @limit;
```

Note that technically we could have used the alias in the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING income > @limit;
```

But this would not be portable to most other databases.  Also, I introduced aliases into the query, which make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

For aggreagte columns not present in the original table you should use `having` clause instead of `where`

```
SET @limit=50;
SELECT customers.`fname`, customers.`lname` ,ROUND(SUM(sales.store_sales)) as income,times.the_year
 FROM `sales` 
 LEFT JOIN times
 ON sales.time_id=times.time_id
 LEFT JOIN customers 
ON customers.customer_id=sales.customer_id 
WHERE `total_children`=0
GROUP BY customers.customer_id,times.the_year 
having income>@limit
```

Comment: It will not work. Because the selected list is not in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @the.salman.a Actually it will, MySQL allows using aliases given to aggregated columns in `having` clause (compared for example to Oracle who doesn't allow it)

Comment: That part is okay, I am talking about selected list. It'll give this `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'image_processing.customers.fname' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: @the.salman.a As you can see from the error you get it's not allowed in SQL mode you've set (or which was set by default in your session). Changing SQL mode will solve the problem as MySQL allows non-aggregate columns in select list though started discouraging it's usage.

Comment: yeah. That's also there. You got it.

Comment: @the.salman.a Actually, grouping by `customers.customer_id`, assuming it's the primary key of that table, means that we may select _any_ other column in that table because they are functionally dependent on that primary key.  So the only full group by error is not applicable here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yep I got it. That Mode was my issue.

Comment: No...I'm saying that his query will work _in any mode_.  If we group by a primary key in MySQL then we may always select any other column in that table.

Answer (score 0):

income is alias name,so can't use that in where condition.

```
SET @limit=50;
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT customers.`fname`, customers.`lname` ,ROUND(SUM(sales.store_sales)) 
       as income,times.the_year
FROM `sales` LEFT JOIN times ON sales.time_id=times.time_id
             LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.customer_id=sales.customer_id 
WHERE  `total_children`=0
GROUP BY sales.customer_id,times.the_year 
)t WHERE income>@limit
```

Answer (score 0):

> Find the list of the customers with no child and an yearly_income
>   greater that a limit given by the user when running the query.

Are you sure you don't want a simple query like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM customers AS c 
WHERE yearly_income > @limit  -- but why is yearly_income a VarChar(50)?
AND total_children=0
```

Comment: there is no yearly income field

Comment: Of course there is, at least in the `CREATE TABLE customers` you posted :-)

Comment: ,sorry yes.so how we find it? yearly income field is a varchar field with data like $30K - $50K

Comment: There's https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index, e.g. `substring_index( '$30K - $50K', '-', 1)` returns `'$30K`.

Comment: SELECT substring_index( yearly_income, '-', -1) FROM customers

Comment: @doneth,how remove $ and K SELECT substring_index( yearly_income, '-', -1) FROM customers

Comment: For me *greater than a limit* translates to the 1st value

Comment: @doneth please tell how extract upper limit without any symbols?

Comment: Play around with substring: `substring('$30K' from 2 for position('K' in '$30K')-2)` or trim: `trim(trailing 'K ' from trim(leading '$' from '$30K')`

Comment: how remove symbols

Comment: Which symbols, `$`?

Comment: I wrote that 2 hours ago: Play around with substring: `substring('$30K' from 2 for position('K' in '$30K')-2)` or trim: `trim(trailing 'K ' from trim(leading '$' from '$30K')`