# mysql group concat unknow column error

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to search for query on first name and last name field

here is my query

```
SELECT d.title, GROUP_CONCAT(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName) as fullname
FROM DEALS d 
left JOIN USER u ON u.idUser = d.userId 
WHERE ((d.title LIKE  '%goutham%' OR d.keywords LIKE  '%goutham%')
OR fullname LIKE  '%goutham%') AND d.isPublic=1
```

But i got

> Unknown column 'fullname' in 'where clause'

Comment: Well what is `goutham`?  Is it a first name, last name, or both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: Please show us some sample data if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its actually a firstname

Comment: Please explain what you want. Since your query is invalid, we can only guess your intention. Best would be to post sample data and expected result.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I would like to get all the rows deals table that the keyword matches both first name and last name in the user table

Comment: That is not enough information. Do you want one row per deal or one row per user? Do you need the user names in the result?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column alias in `where`.  It has nothing to do with the rest of your query.

You don't have a `GROUP BY`, so I suspect `GROUP_CONCAT()` is not intended.  Instead you want `CONCAT()`.  You can repeat the expression in the `WHERE`, but I think you should look in each component:

```
SELECT d.title, CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName) as fullname
FROM DEALS d left JOIN USER
     u
     ON u.idUser = d.userId 
WHERE (d.title LIKE '%goutham%' OR
       d.keywords LIKE '%goutham%' OR
       u.firstName LIKE '%goutham%' OR
       u.lastName LIKE '%goutham%'
      ) AND
      d.isPublic = 1;
```

If you care about performance and are looking for words, then you might want to look into MySQL's full text index capabilities.

If you still want to look on the combination, I would recommend repeating the expression:

```
WHERE (d.title LIKE '%goutham%' OR
       d.keywords LIKE '%goutham%' OR
       CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName) LIKE '%goutham%'
      ) AND
      d.isPublic = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of your problem is that you can't refer to an alias defined in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause of the same query.  The solution would be to repeat the entire expression instead of using the alias.  However, based on your comment, you really want to check the first name, so do just that:

```
SELECT
    d.title,
    CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName) AS fullname
FROM DEALS d 
LEFT JOIN USER u
    ON u.idUser = d.userId 
WHERE
    (d.title LIKE '%goutham%' OR
    d.keywords LIKE '%goutham%' OR
    u.firstName LIKE  '%goutham%') AND d.isPublic = 1;
```

Comment: But if I want to search on the combination like (firstName and lastName) is it possible with this query?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  What is `goutham`?  Are you looking for a first or last name?  Keep in mind that your `fullname` alias is a concatenation with a space of two other fields.