# query 1 to Many in one record with filter in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, one-to-many

i've in a MariaDB's schema these tables:

```
CLIENTI
id           | ragionesociale      | idZucchetti   | MORE COLS....
1            | SEA srl             | 569           | ....
2            | Contoso Srl         | 700           | ....
...

RIFERIMENTI_CLIENTI
ID  | riferimento         | idtipo        | idCliente  | MORE COLS....
1   | info@seasrl.it      | 2             | 1          | ....
2   | 003905623547        | 1             | 1          | ....
3   | 003905685748        | 6             | 1          | ....
4   | info@contoso.it     | 2             | 2          | ....
5   | 0039562475          | 1             | 2          | ....
6   | 00398562586         | 6             | 2          | .... 
...
```

The basic SELECT statement I am making now is

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS c.idzucchetti,
                           c.ragionesociale,
                           c.indirizzo,
                           c.citta,
                           c.cap,
                           c.prov,
                           (SELECT riferimento
                            FROM   riferimenti_clienti AS rc
                            WHERE  rc.idcliente = c.id
                                   AND rc.idanagrafica = -1
                                   AND idtipo = 1) AS tel,
                           (SELECT riferimento
                            FROM   riferimenti_clienti AS rc
                            WHERE  rc.idcliente = c.id
                                   AND rc.idanagrafica = -1
                                   AND idtipo = 6) AS fax,
                           (SELECT riferimento
                            FROM   riferimenti_clienti AS rc
                            WHERE  rc.idcliente = c.id
                                   AND rc.idanagrafica = -1
                                   AND idtipo = 2) AS email
FROM   clienti AS c
```

that produce this result

```
QUERY RESULT
idZucchetti  | ragionesociale  ... | tel              | fax              | email
569          | SEA srl             | 003905623547     | 003905685748     | info@seasrl.it
700          | Contoso Srl         | 0039562475       | 00398562586      | info@contoso.it
```

first question: is the correct way to get the results?

second question: I need to filter on the tel, fax or email columns.
When I write in the "WHERE" clause

```
tel LIKE '%...%'
```

or fax or email, I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'tel' in 'where clause'
```

how can I do?

Comment: first question: What is your query supposed to be doing?  You never told us this, and no one should have to moll over your query to try to fill in this gap.

Comment: Convert the sub-queries to LEFT JOIN's. Safer and you can use their columns in the ON/WHERE clause.

Comment: @jarlh besides LEFT JOIN, a group By is also needed, otherwise duplicate rows would appear. It looks like table structure is based on EAV Model

Comment: A more common method (though not necessarily the most efficient) is to use `MAX(CASE WHEN... THEN...) ... GROUP BY` - it's a standard pivot pattern though so thousands of example out there

Comment: You can't use aliases in `WHERE` clauses. Add those conditions to a `HAVING` clause instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya is the query with joins and groupby efficient?

Comment: @Nick thanks with HAVING work

Comment: @majinb_igor no worries. Glad you got it working.

Comment: @majinb_igor It is *generally* more efficient than using multiple correlated subqueries. Also, depends on the indexing defined.