# Laravel - How do add DB::raw with specific Where clause to existing Query

Tags: laravel

I want to add DB::raw() with specific where clause to existing query.

I have this Query:

```
    protected static $type = 
    [
        'daily' => 1,
        'weekly' => 2,
        'montly' => 3,
    ];

    $revenuedetails = DB::table("users")
        ->select("users.username", "users.email",DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as subscription_date"))
        ->where('users.plan', self::$type[$plan] ?? null);
```

But I want to add this:

```
DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as expired_date"))
where('users.plan_status', 0)
```

It whould be immediately beside

> DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as subscription_date"))

Hence the the structure will now be

username  |  email   |   subscription_date   |   expired_date

I want to add

> DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as expired_date"))

with its own specific where clause

> where('users.plan_status', 0)

to the existing query.

Please note that

> where('users.plan', self::$type[$plan] ?? null)

is the overall where clause.

Then end result should be

> username  |  email   |   subscription_date   |   expired_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, if the plan status = 0 then you want to use the created_at date as the expiration date?  If not, then expired_date should be null?

If so, you can accomplish this with a case statement, like this ...

```
DB::raw(" CASE WHEN users.plan_status = 0 THEN DATE(users.created_at) ELSE null END AS expired_date ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If I understood good you want to use a where on your alias created so you can use "having()" instead of where as follows:

```
$revenuedetails = DB::table("users")
    ->select("users.username", "users.email",DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as subscription_date"), DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as expired_date"))
    ->having("subscription_date", "operador", "Value_condition")
    ->having("expired_date", "operador", "Value_condition")
    ->where('users.plan', self::$type[$plan] ?? null);
```

Also you can check the below reference:

[Can you use an alias in the WHERE clause in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200200/can-you-use-an-alias-in-the-where-clause-in-mysql)

I hope I've helped you

Regards

Comment: I said   DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as expired_date"))  will only be valid where where('users.plan_status', 0).It is not for the general query.   Hence when plan_status is 0 then it has expired. So it does not affect other fields.

Comment: Ok I understood, the solution provided by AndyChern will works for you